# What condition is needed to exit from infinite loop?

Tags: java

I have tried to write server side application. From school, I have leaned that I shouldnot let the code do infinite loop. But, in my server side application, I have not found the way that at what condition I should exit from the infinite loop. The code

```
ServerSocket s = null;
s = new ServerSocket(5000 , 10);

Socket connection = null;
while(true)
{
    connection = s.accept();

    //create new thread to handle client
    new client_handler(connection).start();
}
```

Comment: `I shouldnot let the code do infinite loop.` I wouldn't assume that is correct esp if you want a program which doesn't finish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You usually exit the loop when the JVM is shut down on a server.  Or when an exception is thrown and not caught.    This is one case where the infinite loop is justified.  If all went well, your server would be up forever.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `boolean` flag that you can set to `false` at some point from inside or outside the loop.

```
boolean started = true;
while (started) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If the server should run and accept connections indefinitely, there is no need for exiting the loop.

If there is some command or condition, when the server should terminate, just do so

```
while(true) {
    connection = s.accept();

    //create new thread to handle client
    new client_handler(connection).start();

    if (condition)
       break;
}
```

or even better

```
while (!condition) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

usually for these applications you use some flag to signal termination, like so:

```
private volatile boolean shouldDie = false; //thevolatile bit is important
...
while (!shouldDie) {
   //do some work
}
```

and then when you want the program to terminate you just need to set the flag to tru and wait (this is for graceful termination)

Answer (score 2):

Your `while` statement is always going to evaluate to true, as you've passed in the value `true` rather than using any conditions

Answer (score 1):

You could always do it like this:

```
boolean loopCheck = true;
while(loopCheck)
{
//do stuff
loopCheck = false;
}
```

In PHP, not sure if it works in java,  we can do

```
while(true)
{
//do stuff
break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use a boolean flag.

boolean flag=true;
while(flag)
{
// Your code here

if(condition)   //condition to exit loop
{
flag=false;
}
}
```